# Как в DataFrame оставить все уникальные значения начиная сверху?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, комбинаторика

Как в `df_name_serial_number` оставить все уникальные значения  `df_name_serial_number` начиная сверху?

Приведу два примера, в обоих случаях данные одни и те же, в первом примере данные идут по порядку, во втором примере данные перемешанны (приближенные к реальным). Нужно отобрать уникальные значения обязательно **НАЧИНАЯ СВЕРХУ** в `df_name_serial_number`.

Исходные данные:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

#создаем df
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [5, 6, 7, 8], 'C': [9, 10, 11, 12], 'D': [13, 14, 15, 16], 'E': [17, 18, 19, 20],  'F': [21, 22, 23, 24], 'G': [25, 26, 27, 28], 'H': [29, 30, 31, 32], 'L': [33, 34, 35, 36], 'K': [37, 38, 39, 40], 'M': [41, 42, 43, 44], 'P': [45, 46, 47, 48]})

#создаем df_name_serial_number 
cols = df.columns.to_list()
nums = list(range(len(cols)))

df_name_serial_number = pd.DataFrame(
        [[f"{cols[a]}_{cols[b]}", a, b] for a, b in list(combinations(nums, 2))], 
        columns="name serial_number1 serial_number2".split())
```

1. Пример

Данный пример приведен для понимания:

```
df_name_serial_number
    name  serial_number1  serial_number2

0   A_B               0               1
1   A_C               0               2
2   A_D               0               3
3   A_E               0               4
4   A_F               0               5
5   A_G               0               6
6   A_H               0               7
7   A_L               0               8
8   A_K               0               9
9   A_M               0              10
10  A_P               0              11
11  B_C               1               2
12  B_D               1               3
13  B_E               1               4
14  B_F               1               5
15  B_G               1               6
16  B_H               1               7
17  B_L               1               8
18  B_K               1               9
19  B_M               1              10
20  B_P               1              11
21  C_D               2               3
22  C_E               2               4
23  C_F               2               5
24  C_G               2               6
25  C_H               2               7
26  C_L               2               8
27  C_K               2               9
28  C_M               2              10
29  C_P               2              11
30  D_E               3               4
31  D_F               3               5
32  D_G               3               6
33  D_H               3               7
34  D_L               3               8
35  D_K               3               9
36  D_M               3              10
37  D_P               3              11
38  E_F               4               5
39  E_G               4               6
40  E_H               4               7
41  E_L               4               8
42  E_K               4               9
43  E_M               4              10
44  E_P               4              11
45  F_G               5               6
46  F_H               5               7
47  F_L               5               8
48  F_K               5               9
49  F_M               5              10
50  F_P               5              11
51  G_H               6               7
52  G_L               6               8
53  G_K               6               9
54  G_M               6              10
55  G_P               6              11
56  H_L               7               8
57  H_K               7               9
58  H_M               7              10
59  H_P               7              11
60  L_K               8               9
61  L_M               8              10
62  L_P               8              11
63  K_M               9              10
64  K_P               9              11
65  M_P              10              11
```

Как сделать вот такой результат, чтобы остались только уникальные значения в `df_name_serial_number` **НАЧИНАЯ СВЕРХУ**? Если внимательно посмотреть, во всех трех столбцах остались уникальные значения:

```
df_name_serial_number
   name  serial_number1  serial_number2
0  A_B               0               1
1  C_D               2               3
2  E_F               4               5
3  G_H               6               7
4  L_K               8               9
5  M_P              10              11
```

2. Пример

В этом случае, а точнее всегда, они будут перемешены `df_name_serial_number`.

```
    name  serial_number1  serial_number2
0   A_K               0               9
1   A_E               0               4
2   F_P               5              11
3   A_C               0               2
4   B_D               1               3
5   A_G               0               6
6   K_P               9              11
7   A_L               0               8
8   A_B               0               1
9   A_M               0              10
10  A_P               0              11
11  B_C               1               2
12  A_F               0               5
13  B_E               1               4
14  B_F               1               5
15  B_G               1               6
16  B_H               1               7
17  B_L               1               8
18  B_K               1               9
19  B_M               1              10
20  B_P               1              11
21  C_D               2               3
22  C_E               2               4
23  C_F               2               5
24  C_G               2               6
25  C_H               2               7
26  C_L               2               8
27  C_K               2               9
28  C_M               2              10
29  C_P               2              11
30  D_E               3               4
31  D_F               3               5
32  D_G               3               6
33  D_H               3               7
34  D_L               3               8
35  D_K               3               9
36  D_M               3              10
37  D_P               3              11
38  E_F               4               5
39  E_G               4               6
40  E_H               4               7
41  E_L               4               8
42  E_K               4               9
43  E_M               4              10
44  E_P               4              11
45  F_G               5               6
46  F_H               5               7
47  F_L               5               8
48  F_K               5               9
49  F_M               5              10
50  A_D               0               3
51  G_H               6               7
52  G_L               6               8
53  G_K               6               9
54  G_M               6              10
55  G_P               6              11
56  H_L               7               8
57  H_K               7               9
58  H_M               7              10
59  H_P               7              11
60  L_K               8               9
61  L_M               8              10
62  L_P               8              11
63  K_M               9              10
64  A_H               0               7
65  M_P              10              11
```

Как сделать вот такой результат? Чтобы остались только уникальные значения **НАЧИНАЯ СВЕРХУ** во всем `df_name_serial_number`:

```
df_name_serial_number
   name  serial_number1  serial_number2
0   A_K               0               9
2   F_P               5               11
4   B_D               1               3
22  C_E               2               4
51  G_H               6               7
61  L_M               8              10
```

Comment: Чисто imho. Ни в коем случае не претендуя на истину в последней инстанции. Учите SQL

Comment: @OleLukøje, бесспорно знание SQL - очень полезный навык, но не совсем понятно как он поможет в данном случае) Даже если перенести этот DataFrame в SQL таблицу, то написать нужный запрос на чистом SQL, по-моему,  не получиться - придётся писать монстрообразные UDF (user defined functions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
s = set()
keys = []

for name in df_name_serial_number["name"]:
    a,b = name.split("_")
    if a not in s and b not in s:
        keys.append(name)
        s |= set([a, b])

res = df_name_serial_number.query("name in @keys")
```

---

результат:

```
In [79]: res
Out[79]:
   name  serial_number1  serial_number2
0   A_K               0               9
2   F_P               5              11
4   B_D               1               3
22  C_E               2               4
51  G_H               6               7
61  L_M               8              10
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам ! " MaxU "

Comment: @VEL, всегда пожалуйста)